# postgres 9 replication - replicating only one database

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL 9.0, can I configure the PostgreSQL not to replicate a certain database? I have three databases and I want to replicate only two.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't, that's not supported. PostgreSQL uses log shipping, so everything in WAL is shipped and processed on the slave.

Take a look at [Slony](http://slony.info/), that will solve your problem.

Comment: Slony is the appropriate solution, so have an upvote. Having worked with it, however, I'd suggest that the OP do literally ANYTHING within their power to use Postgres 9's replication instead. Slony is an administrative tar-pit with extremely eccentric behavior, bizarre restrictions that mess you up at wierd times (no DDL without piping it through a special script, strange locking behavior, on and on), and a generally hellish threshold of reliability that is anything but enterprise-ready. I've admin'd Slony for relatively simple use cases for six months now, and I want that half a year back.

Comment: what do you means exactly slony is not a good thing sorry i'm not that good in english.